# get normalized or find title from page with nodejs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, web-crawler, google-search

im using `var tmp_title = $('title').text();` with `cheerio.js` to get a title from a page.

question, is there anything that could normalizse a string or remove html entities like `\n\t` or `\n` etc?

Example

```
\n\t defense.gov news article: thousands lay wreaths at arlington cemetery gravesites\n
```

Into

```
Thousand lay wreaths at arlington cemetery gravesites
```

or is there a way to get the title from a page? how can google now that the title is at `<h3>` tag or does google crawler get the title from `<title>` tag and remove and normalize title to get a readable title string?

Comment: $('title').text().trim()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make some analysis between:

- head > title
- og:metas of the page: $('meta[name="og:title"]).attr('content')
- hN (descending the hierarchy to get the first hN which is the only one on the page)

Then the "analysis" could be as basic as

- trimming
- taking the smallest common string sequence between all 3 choices

Or, you don't mind relying on some saas web service, you could have a look at http://www.diffbot.com/ .